# Philosophy of weirdness

Tags: metaphysics

I have curiosity to know is there any probability

that superheroes exist.

So my question is,

If "many worlds theory" is proven does that mean all superheroes would exist?

Answer (score 1):

One has to be careful with these many world theories. An infinite number of worlds doesn't mean that every world you can imagine would exist.
Just think about it as a mathematical concept : you have an infinite number of natural numbers, but it doesn't mean you can find 1/2 among them. It just means that if something as a probability to happen, even if it's a small probabilty, it will happen if you have enough world.

Otherwise the "world that have already destroy all the other world" would exist and we won't be here to discuss.

Comment: Only possible worlds can exist - perhaps the destroyer world is not possible.

Comment: Yes I agree. So even if a large number of world exist, if a world with superhero is not possible it should not exist. So a many world theory doesn't imply that superhero exist.

Comment: Batman could exist.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen : Batman doesn't have superpowers. Can we really consider that he is a superhero ? But yeah I agree, I don't see any reason for Batman not to exist if there is a really large amount of worlds. And by large I mean large enough to compensate the low probability for him to appear in one world.

Answer (score 0):

The many worlds theory is a modern variation of the concept of [Eternal Return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_return), according to which every possible superhero must have already existed.

The concept is poetically described by Nietzsche in his magnum opus:

[Thus Spake Zarathustra](http://philosophy.eserver.org/nietzsche-zarathustra.txt) - 46. The Vision and the Enigma

> "Look at this gateway! Dwarf!" I continued, "it hath two faces. Two
>   roads come together here: these hath no one yet gone to the end of.
>   This long lane backwards: it continueth for an eternity. And that long
>   lane forward- that is another eternity.   They are antithetical to one
>   another, these roads; they directly abut on one another:- and it is
>   here, at this gateway, that they come together. The name of the
>   gateway is inscribed above: 'This Moment.'   But should one follow
>   them further- and ever further and further on, thinkest thou, dwarf,
>   that these roads would be eternally antithetical?"-   "Everything
>   straight lieth," murmured the dwarf, contemptuously. "All truth is
>   crooked; time itself is a circle."   "Thou spirit of gravity!" said I
>   wrathfully, "do not take it too lightly! Or I shall let thee squat
>   where thou squattest, Haltfoot,- and I carried thee high!"
>   "Observe," continued I, "This Moment! From the gateway, This Moment,
>   there runneth a long eternal lane backwards: behind us lieth an
>   eternity.   Must not whatever can run its course of all things, have
>   already run along that lane? Must not whatever can happen of all
>   things have already happened, resulted, and gone by?

Incidentally, in this video - [The Astonishing Simplicity of Everything](http://perimeterinstitute.ca/videos/neil-turok-astonishing-simplicity-everything) - Professor Neil Turok treats the many worlds theory with some scepticism and faint disdain.